# Nest inside <Image> but behind the image

Tags: image, reactjs, react-native

The problem I'm having is that the image inside the image, is on top of the outside image, the outside image is a half transparent image so I want it to be ON TOP of the nested image, as an overlay image, what can I do?

```
  <Image
    style={it}
    source={require('../../img/Rarities/red.png')}
  >
  <View>
      {
        item[2] != null ?
          <View style={{ width: 15, height: 15, backgroundColor: item[2].Color }} />
        : null
      }
    <Image
      style={{height:'70%',width:'70%'}}
      source={{ uri: item[1].base64 }}
    />
  </View>
  </Image>
```

**I tried:**

changing the zIndex of the images didn't work..

Comment: But the outside image has to be bigger than the inside image...

Comment: provide a screen shot

Answer (score 0):

In React Native, components are rendered in the order they are defined - therefore it can be tricky to reverse the order and render a parent on top of a child.

Instead, you can render the images as siblings, and use a parent container component with a little `position: absolute` trickery to get the images to align on top of each other.

For the following view structure:

```
<View style={styles.imageContainer}>
  <Image source={{uri: image1}} style={styles.bottom} />
  <Image source={{uri: image2}} style={styles.top} />
</View>
```

You can achieve this effect with following styles. See inline comments for explanation:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  // The container controls the top image size
  imageContainer: {
    width: 200,
    height: 200
  },
  bottom: {
    // horizontal margin: (100% -width) / 2
    marginHorizontal: '15%',
    // vertical margin: (100% - height) / 2
    marginVertical: '15%',
    width: '70%',
    height: '70%'  
  },
  top: {
    // positioned absolutely
    position: 'absolute',
    opacity: 0.5,
    // full width/height of imageContainer
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%'
  },
});
```

You can see it in action in this [Snack demo](https://snack.expo.io/r1Jj0mcuW).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that i understand what are you meaning correctly but you can use the `Image` components like this if you want to have them inside each other:

```
  <View>
    <Image
      style={{flex:1}}
      source={require('./img/favicon.png')}
    />
    <Image
      style={{height:'30',width:'30', position:'absolute'}}
      source={require('./img/favicon.png')}
    />
  </View>
```

Note: the `Image` sources and the dimensions should be replaced.